# Ruby syntax in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am currently doing the ruby on rails beginner tutorials and I do not understand the specific syntax of migrations.

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Specifically, I do not understand the syntax within the method change on line 3.

What does create_table refers to?

What does :articles means? Is it a symbol?

What is the |t| in this case referring to. To a new table?

Any context and deeper explanations of this code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby libraries often use "DSLs" (domain specific languages). This is an example of one, however once you understand Ruby syntax you can see that it is , in fact, just regular Ruby.

You are right that `create_table` is a method call, and `:articles` is a symbol.

Also remember that functions in ruby can take block arguments, which have two possible syntaxes:

```
[1,2,3].each { |num| <block content> }

# or ..
[1,2,3].each do |num|
  <block content>
end
```

In here `|num|` is a block argument. Under the hood, `each` will take the input and pass each element one-by-one to the block. We refer to the current element by this block argument.

So, taking all this into consideration, we can rewrite this function call like so:

```
create_table(:articles) do |table|
  <do stuff with table>
end
```

Remember that the parenthesis are usually optional in Ruby, which is why it can be written as `create_table :articles`

In more plain language, what this is saying is "create a table with the name *articles*, and then customize that table with the block". It's inside the block that individual columns are added to the table.

I would recommnend reading up more on Ruby blocks since it's a very valuable and important concept.

If you want to write a method that takes a regular argument and a block, it might look like so:

```
def my_function(symbol)
  yield(symbol)
end
```

And then calling it:

```
my_function :some_symbol do |symbol|
  puts "the value is #{symbol}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you!
I still do not understand this notation -> t.string  :name
I understand what it does.. but I don't find any documentation on it.

I did found this link, explaining create_table.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

It says that once you use create_table, you have access to the table object and can use the add_column format.

However, I do not understand how I am suppose to go from this:
add_column(table_name, column_name, type, options), to this:
 t.string :title

I did not find any doc on the "table object" explaining the notation.

Comment: I'm not really sure where the docs for that are. But `string` is a method on the table. There are similar methods for other data types such as `text` and `float`. The argument passed to that method is `:name` which becomes the name of the column. Options can also be passed here